# User interface suggestion for 2 Buttons in Android

Tags: gui-design, layout, android

So I am making an android application in which in one of the activities I want the user to choose a photograph either from the "gallery" or by taking a picture from the "camera".

Presently I have two buttons, in the middle of the layout (one for "Gallery" and one for "Camera").

I was wondering if any of the user interface/design experts out there can suggest me a good way to put this in my layout.

Any widget suggestions are also welcomed.

I want it to solve two purposes, ease of use as well as good looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some design patterns for Android that implement this are

- Standard 'Complete using' dialog with Camera and Gallery included as options.
- Directly enter the camera screen, and include an icon to choose image from gallery.

[image: Complete using dialog in Cluster]
[image: Camera screen on Instagram]

Comment: Wow, that was a nice suggestion. ! I will wait for more comments, if I don't get many then I will mark your answer as "answered"